# How to push object value instead of reference of the object in array

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I created an object and tried to push it on one array.
When I tried to add an object the first time in the array so it's added perfectly, but when I edit the object and again push the object to the same array. But both values in the array look like same.

In an array it's pushing reference of my object, when it's changed, then also reflected in the array.

Can please someone help me to push object values in the array not the reference of the object?

```
void checkedItem(int id) {
    obj!.clear();
    obj = {
      "id": id,
      "items": {
        "artical": "",
        "item": "",
        "vol": "",
        "pc/ctm": "",
        "total": "",
        "option": false,
        "action": "",
      },
    };

    filterList!['special_cases'].forEach((data) {
      if (data['value'] == true) {
        temp.add(obj);
      }
    });
    filterList!['categories'].forEach((data) {
      data['subCategories'].forEach((item) {
        if (item['value'] == true) {
          obj!['items']['item'] = item['name'];
          temp.add(obj);
        }
      });
    });
    // print(temp);
    update();
  }

  void addPhaseItem() {
    phaseData.add(temp);
    print(phaseData);
    Get.back();
    temp.clear();
    update();
  }
```

[image: output of my code]

Comment: try to identify first if the id is duplicate in the list using where if not then add the new one

Comment: Quick question: what does this have to do with firestore? (I concur with @ArbiterChil , a check to see if the item already exists in the list is a good idea if you're using generic objects)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
temp.add(obj);
```

with

```
temp.add({...obj}); // note the curly braces for maps and sets
```

in all cases.

"..." is the spread operator, and allows you to insert items from one collection into another. You can read more about them on the Dart Language Tour page.

Comment: not working same issue

Comment: That's strange, because the code I've written works fine on dartpad. Can you show me the rest of your code as well? I'm wondering where "checkedItem" is called, and whether you're accidentally overwriting your own list.